# Auto shorthand notation CSS in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I'm writing CSS it will happen that I write group options separate. For example

```
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
```

In visual studio 2013 I get a notification:

`Preformance: Use shorthand notation`

Not that it is a problem I can edit by myself, but I'm just curios if there is a short key that auto shorthands these options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

The padding property can have from one to four values.

```
padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
```

top padding is 25px
right padding is 50px
bottom padding is 75px
left padding is 100px

```
padding: 25px 50px 75px;
```

top padding is 25px
right and left paddings are 50px
bottom padding is 75px

```
padding: 25px 50px;
```

top and bottom paddings are 25px
right and left paddings are 50px

```
padding: 25px;
```

all four paddings are 25px

from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: Yes I know ;-) But that is not the question. I was searching for a auto shorthand function in visual studio ;-)

Comment: @S.Visser Oh, Sorry for inappropriate answer.